# Making animation work on a disabled control

Tags: .net, wpf, animation, storyboard, disabled-control

I am using an animation to change the background and foreground color of a control, whenever its value changes; it's working fine except for controls which are disabled. Here is the animation I am using

```
<Storyboard
    x:Key="Anim"
    AutoReverse="True"
    Duration="500"
    FillBehavior="Stop">
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.002">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" />
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.002">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="White" />
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

I am setting the target for this animation at run time like this -

```
Storyboard anim = this.FindResource("Anim") as Storyboard;
if (anim != null)
{
    anim.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetProperty, animationTarget);
}
```

and whenever value changes I do

```
_animation.Begin();
```

Note that target control can be of different type e.g. TextBox, DropDown, CheckBox etc. and can be Enabled or Disabled based on ViewModel property.

How can I make this animation work for disabled controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem in rather easy way by using [BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.booleananimationusingkeyframes%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). I added BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames to my animation, so when this animation is applied control becomes enabled for short time interval, animation runs and the control is again disabled.

Blogged about this here - [Making animations work for disabled controls](http://weblogs.asp.net/akjoshi/archive/2012/06/13/Making-Animations-work-for-disabled-control.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the reason that it doesn't work for disabled controls is because, inside the style of the control, when it is in the disabled visual state, there is a `Rectangle` or a `Border` showing up and it overlays the `Background` panel.

You probably need to create an attached property (e.g. `DisabledBackground`) and use `TemplateBinding` to make it bind to the `Background` of the disabled panel. Then you just need to animate this `DisabledBackground` property to a transparent color.

Comment: Thanks Xin, yes something like that is causing this behavior, but if I decide to name this panel then I would have to override the control templates for so many controls(textbox, DropDown..)!

Comment: Sorry, naming the panel wouldn't work, you probably need an attached property here... I don't think there is an easy way around...